# Symfony2 No mapping file found

Tags: symfony

am working on symfony2 and am geting this error:

> No mapping file found named 'Acme.BlogBundle.Entity.Posts.php' for
>   class 'Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Posts'. 500 Internal Server Error -
>   MappingException

I generate Entity php **app/console doctrine:generate:entity**

Name of entity: **AcmeBlogBundle:Post**

Format: **php**

All that i put in **Acme:BlogBundle:Entity** directory.

This is my Entity Post class with getter and setter methds:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Posts
 */
class Posts
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $shortText;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $longText;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $dateModified;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Posts
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set shortText
     *
     * @param string $shortText
     * @return Posts
     */
    public function setShortText($shortText)
    {
        $this->shortText = $shortText;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shortText
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getShortText()
    {
        return $this->shortText;
    }

    /**
     * Set longText
     *
     * @param string $longText
     * @return Posts
     */
    public function setLongText($longText)
    {
        $this->longText = $longText;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get longText
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLongText()
    {
        return $this->longText;
    }

    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param string $author
     * @return Posts
     */
    public function setAuthor($author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateCreated
     * @return Posts
     */
    public function setDateCreated($dateCreated)
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $dateCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateCreated()
    {
        return $this->dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateModified
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateModified
     * @return Posts
     */
    public function setDateModified($dateModified)
    {
        $this->dateModified = $dateModified;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateModified
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateModified()
    {
        return $this->dateModified;
    }
}
```

In my controller i first set Post Entity after definig namespace of controller.

```
use Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Posts;
```

After that i create method

```
    public function AddAction()
    { 

        // $post = Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Posts()

         $posts = new Posts();
         $posts->setTitle('Test Title');

         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         $em->persist($posts);
         $em->flush();
}
```

Here is and **Stack Trace** output

> [1] Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: No mapping
>   file found named 'Acme.BlogBundle.Entity.Posts.php' for class
>   'Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Posts'.
>   at n/a
>   in /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php
>   line 74
>
> at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::mappingFileNotFound('Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Posts',
>   'Acme.BlogBundle.Entity.Posts.php')
>   in /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/DefaultFileLocator.php
>   line 117
>
> at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\DefaultFileLocator->findMappingFile('Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Posts')
>   in /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/PHPDriver.php
>   line 59
>
> at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\PHPDriver->loadMetadataForClass('Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Posts',
>   object(ClassMetadata))
>   in /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php
>   line 104
>
> at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass('Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Posts',
>   object(ClassMetadata))
>   in /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php
>   line 113
>
> ```
> at Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(object(ClassMetadata),
> ```
>
> null, false, array())
>           in /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php
>   line 302
>
> ```
> at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Posts')
>     in /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php
> ```
>
> line 205
>
> at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Posts')
>   in /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php
>   line 268
>
> at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata('Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Posts')
>   in /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>   line 1580
>
> at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->doPersist(object(Posts), array('000000000d824498000000009cdc8511' => object(Posts)))
>   in /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>   line 1555
>
> at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->persist(object(Posts))
>   in /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php
>   line 565
>
> at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->persist(object(Posts))
>           in /var/www/html/Symfony/src/Acme/BlogBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
>   line 23
>
> at Acme\BlogBundle\Controller\DefaultController->indexAction()
>   in  line
>
> at call_user_func_array(array(object(DefaultController), 'indexAction'), array())
>   in /var/www/html/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2815
>
> at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request),
>   '1')
>   in /var/www/html/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2789
>
> at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1',
>   true)
>   in /var/www/html/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2918
>
> at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request),
>   '1', true)
>   in /var/www/html/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2220
>
> at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
>   in /var/www/html/Symfony/web/app_dev.php line 28

Update:

**New Entity Test:**

```
<?php
// src/Acme/BlogBundle/Entity/Test.php
namespace Acme\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="short_text", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $shortText;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="long_text", type="text")
     */
    private $longText;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreated;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Test
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set shortText
     *
     * @param string $shortText
     * @return Test
     */
    public function setShortText($shortText)
    {
        $this->shortText = $shortText;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shortText
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getShortText()
    {
        return $this->shortText;
    }

    /**
     * Set longText
     *
     * @param string $longText
     * @return Test
     */
    public function setLongText($longText)
    {
        $this->longText = $longText;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get longText
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLongText()
    {
        return $this->longText;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateCreated
     * @return Test
     */
    public function setDateCreated($dateCreated)
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $dateCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateCreated()
    {
        return $this->dateCreated;
    }
}
```

Again the some error

**$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle**

> Generating entities for bundle "AcmeBlogBundle"
>
> ```
>                                                                 [RuntimeException]
> ```
>
> Bundle "AcmeBlogBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.
>
> doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name

Answer (score 2):

You should add mapping information for fields. [Read more](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information)

Like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

Comment: Man i read that 1000 times after post this. If u know what is corect problem than say what to add or remove.

Comment: I've edited the answer. take attention about annotations for properties

Comment: Check update for my new Entity `test` and again the some problem.

Answer (score 1):

I made the mistake of adding a new Entity through console with a mapping type of 'php' instead of my default 'annotations'. Immediately without even touching the generated class my site wouldn't load. It threw this MappingException for my user class.

I removed the new Entity class thinking that would fix it, and everything else I could think of.  Then I looked in my app/Resources/config directory.  There was a new directory called Doctrine. It contained a mapping file for the Entity that caused the issue.  When I removed this directory and file, the Exception was gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use annotations to defining your mapping, just select the option "annotations" when you generate your entity.

Comment: -1 Like what i say, u dont read full this topic. First i use php the seccond update i use annotation and entity whit annotation is posted.

Comment: So if you use php mapping, what looks like your "Acme.BlogBundle.Entity.Posts.php" file ? can you post it ?

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is quite old I don't want to keep a secret how I solved it. It seems that I had an old mapping files reference in the cache because I moved it to another folder. Clearing the cache solved the issue for me.